# Mismatched types error when implementing a generic struct with a specific type parameter

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a generic struct A1Implementation that takes a type parameter B which should implement the trait A1. However, when I try to create an instance of A1Implementation with a specific type Ex1_A1, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
mismatched types
expected type parameter `B`
       found struct `Ex1_A1`
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
struct A1Implementation<B: A1>(B);

impl <B: A1> Default for A1Implementation<B> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self(Ex1_A1)
    }
}
```

I understand that the error is indicating that the expected type parameter B is not the same as the found type Ex1_A1. However, Ex1_A1 does indeed implement the A1 trait.

Could someone help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can achieve a similar behavior? I want to create an instance of A1Implementation with a specific type that implements the A1 trait.

Answer (score 2):

`Self` *always* means "the type in the `impl` clause".

The type in the `impl` clause is `A1Implementation<B>`, which is not the same as  `A1Implementation<Ex1_A1>` that you return.

You have two options:

1. Implement `Default` for any `A1Implementation`, and return the default value for `B`:

   ```rust
   impl<B: A1 + Default> Default for A1Implementation<B> {
       fn default() -> Self {
           Self(B::default())
       }
   }
   ```

   (This impl can be derived).

   This allows any type parameter to be used with the `Default` impl, but does not provide a default type for it.
2. Impl `Default` only for `A1Implementation<Ex1_A1>`:

   ```rust
   impl Default for A1Implementation<Ex1_A1> {
       fn default() -> Self {
           Self(Ex1_A1)
       }
   }
   ```

   This chooses the opposite trade-off: allow only `Ex1_A1`, but also default to it.

Comment: Good explanation. For OP, another way to think about generic impls is that you are basically writing code that the compiler is going to copy for each concrete type that satisfies that impl (also called monomorphization).

Say you had another type `Ex2_A1` that also implemented the trait `A1`; your original generic impl of `Default` would result in the compiler creating a `Default` impl for `AllImplementation<Ex2_A1>` that tries to return an instance of `AllImplementation<Ex1_A1>`, which is obviously wrong.

Hope this helps.